# Print NotesEmbeddedObject contents to browser

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have notes document with rich text field. In this RTF there is attachment placed. I would like to redirect (print) this attachment contents in Domino Agent accessed from web browser.

I know I can save NotesEmbeddedObject on disk and then read it and post... but this does not satisfy myself. I am looking for in-memory solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that this was wrong concept.

I used possibility to access files directly on document. Also I have decided to store more than one file in document, thus I decided to make different form for web access and print document list in the way suites my solution:

Here is document with files:
http://ppndev01.ppn.no/PPNWebSite.nsf/files/mifid

Answer (score 1):

If you are using R8, I guess you could use the [DXL utilities](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.designer85.doc/DOC/H_NOTESDXLEXPORTER_CLASS.html) to export the attachments uncompressed (via the `UncompressAttachments` property) and in an agent and dump that to the web browser. Prior to R8, you get the attachment with whatever compression the database uses.

With earlier version of Notes, you can get an stream of the `EmbeddedObject` with Java. This seems to detach the attachment to a temporary file "under the hood".

Comment: I will check Your suggestions ASAP. Thank You.